# No counter 'theorem' defined

Tags: theorems, counters

I'm getting the error No counter 'theorem' defined
Heres my code below

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\newcommand{\package}[1]{\textbf{#1}} % package names in bold text
\newcommand{\cmmd}[1]{\textbackslash\texttt{#1}} % command name in tt font 
\newcommand{\href}[1]{#1}

\usepackage{float}
\restylefloat{table}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{exscale}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{syntonly}
\usepackage[algosection,ruled,lined,boxed,commentsnumbered,linesnumbered,longend]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{lineno}

%\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\makeindex

\newcommand{\beq}{\begin{equation}}
%\newcommand{\bet}{\begin{table}}
\newcommand{\eeq}{\end{equation}}
\newcommand{\real}{\mathbb{R}} %IMPORTANT


\newtheorem{lem}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{thm}[theorem]{Theorem}
\newtheorem{cor}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{rem}[theorem]{Remark}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}
\newtheorem{conj}[theorem]{Conjecture}
```

Comment: Your example is not compilable, but you don't have the `theorem` environment defined. Quick workaround: `\newcounter{theorem}`

Comment: The statement `\newtheorem{thm}[theorem]{Theorem}` doesn't make much sense. Use `\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}` instead -- and place this instruction *before* `\newtheorem{lem}[theorem]{Lemma}`.

Comment: you might benefit from reading the `amsthm` package documentation -- `texdoc amdthm`.  the use of counters is explained pretty clearly there.

Answer (score 10):

Rearrange the `\newtheorem`s as follows, and use `[thm]` instead of `[theorem]`.

```
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{cor}[thm]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{rem}[thm]{Remark}
\newtheorem{remark}[thm]{Remark}
\newtheorem{conj}[thm]{Conjecture}
```

This means that the `thm` environment will use a counter `thm`, and all the other theorem-like environments will use the same counter `thm`.

Here is a complete example.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{cor}[thm]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{rem}[thm]{Remark}
\newtheorem{remark}[thm]{Remark}
\newtheorem{conj}[thm]{Conjecture}
\begin{document}
\begin{thm}
  Some theorem.
\end{thm}
\begin{lem}
  Some lemma.
\end{lem}
\begin{conj}
  A conjecture.
\end{conj}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm having trouble getting this to work
still getting environment lemma undefined  
btw what difference does changing the theorem to thm do?
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
%\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{lemma}
%\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\begin{document}

%\begin{theorem}
%adfasdfadsf
%\end{theorem}

\begin{lemma}
adasd
\end{lemma}

\end{document}

Comment: @HaoSun I've added an example. Check whether it works for you.

Comment: @HaoSun, you can refer to the counter created by the first `\newtheorem{}{}` you use. `\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}` creates a counter named `thm`.

Comment: Okay I see lem is the thing your suppose to enter not lemma I didn't really understand the code thanks everyone